# Lost control of EC2 instance after listen 127.0.0.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I was following an tutorial and by mistake I typed the command `listen 127.0.0.1` and restarted sshd service. When I tried to login again, I got:

> ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused

Did I lost forever access to my server?

Is there any way to connect on the ec2 instance and fix it?

Restarted server, than the same:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3 
...
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname x.x.x.x is address <br>
debug2: ssh_connect_direct debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x port 22. <br>debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused <br>
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused<br>
```

[image: ec2 security table]

[image: ssh login log image]

Is there a way to reset the /etc/ssh/sshd_config from was console?

Sorry, probably the problem was not the listen command but  `PasswordAuthentication yes` entry on `sshd_config`

I believe the solution will be to create a new instance, attach this volume to it, change the file and the return it to previous instance. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: This doesn't seem likely. I suggest you use the EC2 management console to REBOOT the instance and try again. If that doesn't work, use the `-vvv` option when connecting (eg `ssh -vvv -i key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4`) to obtain debugging information. Then Edit your question to show us the log information.

Comment: Are you saying that you also modified `sshd_config`, which likely caused this issue? If so, and you cannot login, then yes the only method is to attach it to another instance that you _can_ login to.

Comment: Thank you! That’s what I’m going to do. :).